# Nextjs - How do I add a list of items to the currently signed in user?

Tags: mongoose, next.js, next-auth

## Goal:

I am trying to create a website where a user logs in and can create a deck of cards on a page called "Deck editor", using the cards that has been entered into a database.
I want the user to be able to save this deck list and have it under their account so that it can then be retrieved later when they log in another time.

## Problem:

I am so far able to save the Deck list to the database but I am unable to associate it with the current user, not only that the field doesn't even appear in the database.

#### What has been accomplished:

- Deck editor can only be accessed if user is logged in.
- A search capability so the user can find the card they want to add.
- Clicking on the search result adds the card into the deck list and clicking on an already added card removes it from the Deck list.
- The ability to switch between 2 types of a deck, "Main" and "Side".

#### What I am using:

- Nextjs
- MongoDB (mongoose to connect Next with Mongo)
- Material UI (Framework for front-end components)
- Next-Auth (to maintain session when user is logged in)

#### Code:

**deckEditing.jsx** file:

```
import { useState } from "react";


export default function SearchPage() {

...
{/* fetch function for http request for the search function and useStates associated with it */}

    const [mainDeck, setMainDeck] = useState([]);
    const [sideDeck, setSideDeck] = useState([]);
    const [selectedDeck, setSelectedDeck] = useState("mainDeck"); 
    const [mainDeckSize, setMainDeckSize] = useState(0);
    const [sideDeckSize, setSideDeckSize] = useState(0);

...
{/* Logic for adding to deck list, removing from deck list and handling the switching between "Main" and "Side" deck. I have also excluded the entire search functionality from this code block */}

return(
    <div>
        <form action="/api/saveDeck" method="post">
        <label htmlFor="deckName">Deck Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter name of deck" required/>
        <h3>Main Deck</h3>
        <input type="radio" value="mainDeck" checked={selectedDeck === "mainDeck"} onChange={handleListChange}/>
        {mainDeck.map((card) => (
        card.quantity === 0 ? <li hidden/> :
        <li onClick={()=>removeFromDeck(card)} key={card._id}><p>{card.name}</p><p>X{card.quantity}</p></li>
        ))}

        {mainDeck.map((card) => (
        <input type="hidden" value = {card._id} name="main" readonly/>
        ))}

    <h3>Side Deck</h3>
    <input type="radio" value="sideDeck" checked={selectedDeck === "sideDeck"} onChange={handleListChange}/>
        {sideDeck.map((card) => (
        card.quantity === 0 ? <li hidden/> :
        <li onClick={()=>removeFromDeck(card)} key={card._id}><p>{card.name}</p><p>X{card.quantity}</p></li>
        ))}

        {sideDeck.map((card) => (
        <input type="hidden" value = {[card._id]} name="side" readonly/>
        ))}

        <p>Main: {mainDeckSize}</p>
        <input type="hidden" value = {mainDeckSize} name="mainSize" readonly/>
        <p>Side: {sideDeckSize}</p>
        <input type="hidden" value = {sideDeckSize} name="sideSize" readonly/>
        <button type="submit">Save button</button>
        </form>
    </div>
)
```

**saveDeck.js** file:

```
require('dotenv').config();
require ('../../utils/mongoDB').connect();
const DeckModel = require('../../models/deck');
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth/next';
import { authOptions } from '../api/auth/[...nextauth]';

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const session = await getServerSession( req, res, authOptions );
    const {name, main, side} = req.body;
    const by = session.user.id;
    let mainSize = Number(req.body.mainSize);
    let sideSize = Number(req.body.sideSize);

    if (req.method !== 'POST') {
        return res.status(400).end("Method is not allowed");
    }
    else if (name === null) {
        return res.status(400).end('Please fill in a name for the deck');
    }
    else {
        const deck = await DeckModel.create({
            name,
            by,
            main,
            side,
            quantity: mainSize + sideSize,
        });
        res.redirect('/deckEditor');
        return res.status(400).end(`Successfully stored "${deck.name}" in database`)
    }
};
```

**deck.js** file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const deckSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    by: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user',
    },
    main: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'card',
    }],
    side: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'card',
    }],
    quantity: {
        type: Number,
    },
});

const DeckModel = mongoose.models.deck || mongoose.model('deck', deckSchema);

module.exports = DeckModel;
```

**user.js** file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        required: true,
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        unique: true,
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
    },
    password: {
        required: true,
        type: String
    },
    token: {
        type: String
    },
    role: {
        //Lowercase, uppercase?
        type: String,
    },
})

const UserModel = mongoose.models.user || mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

module.exports = UserModel;
```

**EDIT 1**:Here is a screenshot of my Deck collection (I have not done any manipulation in Compass and this is what it looks like after clicking the "Save button" on the website. Ignore the quantity field, I know it doesn't match up with the main and side total.)
[image: Deck collection in MongoDB Compass]

**EDIT 2**: After coming back to the project, I have discovered it is now added to the MongoDB collection and the same problem I had with `by`, I also had with `visibility` but not `description`, where I just restarted everything and it started showing.
[image: MongoDB collection with the by, visibility and description field]

If you need more info I'm happy to give more.

Comment: You already have the user id in `by` field in the `deck` model.
So you don't need to keep `decklist` in the `user` model. (By the way it should be an array, even you wanted to keep.) Can you add a few Deck collections to the question so that we see if  indeed the `by` field is there and has user id in it.

Comment: Certainly, I will edit my question so it includes screenshots of my collection.

I didn't think I need `decklist` field either but thanks for reaffirming that.

Comment: I see no `by` field in the collection. Are you sure you get the user.id in this line ` const by = session.user.id;`

Comment: Yes, when I console.log the session.user.id it outputs the id. Also after trying to add multiple entries, the `by` field now shows in the collection.

Comment: So you already accomplished what you wanted. Is there a problem?

Comment: Haha not anymore, thanks for the responses.